# mvn command is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: maven

I am getting the `mvn` command not recognized as an internal or external command.

I have setup the M2_HOME, JAVA_HOME and added %M2_HOME%/bin to the path variable. All are system variables. Still getting the same problem.

Echoing the variables showing me the correct paths.

Path to Maven: `C:\apache-maven-3.1.0\apache-maven-3.1.0`

M2_HOME:`C:\apache-maven-3.1.0\apache-maven-3.1.0`

PATH: `Other things,C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin,C:\apache-maven-3.1.0\apache-maven-3.1.0\bin`

and I have restarted my computer twice.

Comment: it seems the maven installation is not done properly..

Comment: i downloaded apache-maven-3.1.0-bin.zip for windows 7 32 bit and extracted to my location . Then i have setup my variables. Do i need to anything else. If i navigate to the maven bin folder and then pressin mvn then its working fine

Comment: follow [this](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/) tutorial for installing maven.

Comment: Make sure you download maven **binary file** instead of **source code**.

Comment: It might used to work but now it doesn't work anymore. Following these steps keep windows from failing to recognize 'mvn' command.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Restart your machine, after setting up your M2_HOME (pointing to you Maven basedir, ***NOT*** the `bin` dir) and PATH (`PATH=%M2_HOME%\bin;%PATH%`).

Then do:

```
dir "%M2_HOME%\bin\mvn*
```

If there is a `.bat` file, it should work under Windows, as it appears to be finding it. If there isn't one, then your paths are not right and you need to make sure your `%PATH%` variable really points to the correct path to Maven.

Make sure you are using the proper slashes for your OS. Under Windows they're `\`.

Comment: thanks Carl ...i can find my bat file..mvn is still not recornized..what else can i do ?

Comment: Show us your path to Maven, your `M2_HOME` and `PATH` variables and tell us if you've restarted your machine.

Comment: Path to Maven: C:\apache-maven-3.1.0\apache-maven-3.1.0 M2_HOME:C:\apache-maven-3.1.0\apache-maven-3.1.0  PATH: %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Application Virtualization Client;c:\Program Files (x86)\Open Text\View\bin;%systemroot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files\Perforce,C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin,C:\apache-maven-3.1.0\apache-maven-3.1.0\bin and i have restarted my computer twice

Comment: Instead of a ";", you have ",". This is causing your problem. Furthermore, `M2_HOME` should be prepended, not appended, meaning it should be at the very start, not at the end of your `PATH`.

Comment: thanks a lot carlspring...dont know how the ',' came...';' solved the problem

Comment: @carlspring
Why have you added the suffix %PATH% in the M2 PATH (end of your answers 1st sentence)
Also when I reboot my system it doesn't recognize the mvn command & then I need to reconfigure the Maven Home to point to again to the same directory 
My maven path is C:\maven\apache-maven-3.5.4 
M2_Home = C:\maven\apache-maven-3.5.4
PATH configured as %M2_HOME%\bin

Comment: I've appended the `%PATH%` (under Windows, or `$PATH` under Linux/Unix), so that the rest of the `PATH` command is appended after the path to your `M2_HOME` variable. `M2_HOME` is case sensitive on some operating systems.

Answer (score 91):

Right click on My Computer **>>** Properties **>>** Advanced system settings **>>**
***System Properties*** window will get displayed
Under Advanced **>>** Environment Variables

Click on **New** to set Environment Variables

Variable name: **JAVA_HOME**
Variable value: *C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121*

Variable name: **M2**
Variable value: *%M2_HOME%\bin*

Variable name: **M2_HOME**
Variable value:  *C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.5.0*

Variable name:  **Path**
Variable value:  *%M2_HOME%\bin*

Then click on Ok, ok, ok.
Now restart you command prompt and check again with “mvn --version” to verify the mvn is running, you may **restart** your system also.

It should be working now.

Comment: I would like to add that you can just add in the last step instead of %M2_HOME%\bin just M2 in Path variable value

Comment: This is not valid anymore 2022. There is no folder 'C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation'

Comment: I would like to know if all these variables M2, M2_HOME are documented anywhere

Comment: @user1034912, I guess that step should be read like "whatever path your maven is installed at". For that sort of software, I install in a place called `C:\Not Program Files\` for instance

Comment: It might used to work but now it doesn't work anymore. Following these steps keep windows from failing to recognize 'mvn' command.

Answer (score 29):

Write the entire maven path into the Environment **`PATH`** variable.

**Example:**

```
C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.2.3\bin;
```

My `PATH` variable wasn't reading `%M2%` or `%M2_HOME%\bin` properly, and therefore I wrote the full path into the `PATH` variable.

**Working.**

Comment: This worked (Windows 11)

Answer (score 17):

This is worked for me:

1-download apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.tar.gz file from https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

2-copy the folder under c:\programfiles

3-set variables as this:
  M2_HOME  -----   C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9
  M2       -----   C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9

add Path variable to this:   ;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin

then run the cmd as system admin

it worked.

Answer (score 6):

I also was facing with the same issue still after adding path in environment variable and running it as a normal user in command prompt.

Then I opened command prompt and tried running as "**Run as Administrator**" and I was able to download all the packages with respect to the project.

Answer (score 6):

Windows 10 -

1. Add new variable "M2_HOME" -

[image]

2. Update variable "path" -
   [image]
3. Verify on cmd -
   [image]

Answer (score 5):

If you've already set the `JAVA_HOME` and `M2_HOME` (or `MAVEN_HOME` in my case) environment variables and added the **\bin** folder to the `Path` environment variable and still not working, then this solution could be for you.

Make sure that you have set your variables in the right order, your `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` folder should be added before the `%MAVEN_HOME%\bin` just like the shown image

[image: right order of env variables]

[image: wrong order of env variables]

Answer (score 4):

Are you trying to reference a user variable in system variables? Try `echo %path%` and the M2 should have been fully expanded to show the file path to your Maven directory. If it hasn't, then that's the problem.

To fix it, you should create a user variable called `PATH` and add your `%M2%` reference into there.

Comment: What do the parentheses in `%path%` mean?

Comment: @CodyBugstein It means that it's a variable.

Answer (score 4):

Open Command prompt As "Run As a administrator"  and try.

Answer (score 3):

I have a stupid comment but someone else will have that issue.  I was getting that same error when I was trying to put in `./mvnw clean package` and I found out that I had to change it a bit to `.\mvnw clean package`and I lived happily ever after.

Answer (score 2):

Try `%M2_HOME%\bin` (`\` rather than `/`)

Comment: Also sometimes you need to restart Windows.

Answer (score 2):

I faced this problem which kept me busy and buggy for quiet sometime. I was facing the problem (mvn not recognized) after setting up all required environment variables absolutely correctly. So by going by one of the response here, I switched to another version of maven and that fixed the problem.

Not being completely convinced why it worked this way, I then unzipped the problematic-version and updated env-vars which made it work.

The problem was when I initially extracted file from the zip, I modified the directory structure a bit. When you extract the zip, say **apache-maven-X.x.x-bin.zip**, it creates the folder structure as - "apache-maven-3.5.0-bin\apache-maven-3.5.0..."

In my first attempt I had modified this structure by deleting apache-maven-3.5.0-bin folder and bringing apache-maven-3.5.0 structure one folder up. This was causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try with `echo %path%` , if this option doesn't show your `M2_HOME` and others variable values as directory path, then create  a new environment variable lets say `PATH`, and assign like below:

   ```
   PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%M2_HOME%\bin
   ```
2. Add this in variable  `path=.....;%PATH%`
3. Now open a new cmd, and try to `echo %path%`
   it will show all thh system path

Now you can check `mvn -version` it will solve the problem , if not try to restart the system

P.S. as per doc, you should expend your zip distribution in *C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation*. But ideally it doen't matter

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Maven 3+ version. In my case everything was fine. But while adding the M2_HOME along with bin directory, I missed the '\' at the end.
Previously it was like: %M2_HOME%\bin , which was throwing the mvn not recognizable error.
After adding "\" at the end, mvn started working fine. I guess "\" acts as pointer to next folder.
"%M2_HOME%\bin\" Should work, if you missed it.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the path of maven first through command prompt.

`setpath.bat` Open the `cmd` from the base window of the batch file.

The rest maven commands can be used once path is set through `cmd`.

Answer (score 1):

One most important and often overlooked aspect is the %MAVEN_HOME%\bin or %M2_HOME%\bin should be the first thing in the %PATH% environment variable.

Comment: single-line solution should be in comment.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all way finally below step solved the issue .

In the downloaded zip there is file README , in that its mention that
for windows

set PATH="c:\program files\apache-maven-3.x.y\bin";%PATH%

create new PATH variable and assign first maven then %PATH%

it worked out for me .

Try It once

Answer (score 0):

In your Environement variable :

new system variable:

`M2_HOME`     `Your mvn directroy "C:\......\bin"`

new user variable:

`M2`          `%M2_HOME%`

edit the `CLASSPATH` by adding `%M2%`

finally open the cmd and write

`path=%CLASSPATH%`

enjoy

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error but my problem was I had the following:

M2_HOME = C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-2.2.1;

Which meant my PATH = %M2_HOME%\bin; (etc)

...became C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-2.2.1;\bin

i.e. a semicolon was where it shouldn't be.

Which I discovered because [Michael Ferry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19334617/816701) suggested using 'ECHO %PATH%' to see what the actual PATH output was.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. But just restarting my computer after setting up the Maven path resolved the issue.

Variable Name: M2_Home
Variable Value:C:\Apache\apache-maven-3.3.9

Variable Name: Path
Variable Value:C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%JAVA_HOME%\bin\;%M2_HOME%\bin\

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problems. The article that helped me solve similar issues is by MKyong and is here: ****https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/****
It is very important to include in maven's path the file that contains the 'bin','boot', 'conf', 'lib' etc. file folders. For example, in my case, the correct path is: 
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\maven\apache-maven-3.5.0-bin\apache-maven-3.5.0

Answer (score 0):

For me it was not working since I was editing Path variable in "User variable" and adding it under "System variable" made it work. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows you need to do the following:

1. Windows and type env
2. Open the edit environment panel
3. Click Environment Variables
4. In the system variables section, double click Path
5. In the dialog, create a System Variable under Path
   like below ->

   MVN_HOME: C:\Users<username>\Documents\Project\Software\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin
6. Open a new command prompt and hit mvn, you should be able to now.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the issue.
But the problem I faced was due to the location name where the maven was stored on system.
The path did contain spaces due to which system was not able to reach the path leading to this issue.
The issue got resolved for me when I moved the maven to a location which did not contain any spaces.

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers are too complicated. I just fixed the same issue by

```
scoop install maven
```

That requires you install `scoop` the package manager for Windows in the first place.

However I recommend you install the `scoop` so that everything becomes easy.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah so, for me, I fixed it by setting up the M2 variable.
MAVEN_HOME, JAVA_HOME and M2_HOME we set up with their paths, but the command, "mvn -verison" was still showing the error.
So I inserted one more variable, named, "M2" and then set the path of the maven folder (not the bin of the same) and ran the command in cmd.
It worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Adding environment variables from command prompt or windows powershell worked for me. I was able to verify the environment variables present using **"set"** command in command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Just add below in system veriable (change version accordingly)

C:\apache-maven-**3.8.6**\bin

Step 2: Restart system

Step 3: Check maven version
cmd -> **mvn -v**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you working with Jenkins and any solutions don't work, try it:

1. Run cmd.exe
2. Type mvn
3. If you will see "'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command" - try earlier solutions.
4. But if maven shows any statements...
5. Type PATH and press Enter
6. Check if the path to maven is visible in PATH value.
7. If path to maven is visible - I have no idea :-)
8. But if path to maven is not visible...
9. Probably PATH value is to long.
10. Open My Computer >> Properties >> Advanced system settings >> System Properties (System properties - not User Properties)
11. Try to shorten PATH - remove duplications, use indirect variables - %...% etc.
12. Move up "M2_HOME" variable or full maven path to be closer to the beginning of the PATH.
13. Save PATH etc.
14. Close cmd.exe window, and open new.
15. Type PATH and press Enter
16. If path to maven is not visible go to step 9.
17. If path to maven is visible - try run your project in Jenkins.
    I hope it will work :-)

Answer (score -3):

You have written three paths above. The first path (path to maven) should be pointing to the bin directory.

Path to Maven: `C:\apache-maven-3.1.0\apache-maven-3.1.0\bin;`

Below are right. Above path should be corrected.

`M2_HOME:C:\apache-maven-3.1.0\apache-maven-3.1.0;`

`PATH: Other things,C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin,C:\apache-maven-3.1.0\apache-maven-3.1.0\bin;`

Comment: PATH mentioned is incorrect, each path should be seperated by ';' as mentioned @carlspring above