# Aws Sam build failed Error: JavaMavenWorkflow:Resolver - No Maven executable found! on my hello world project

Tags: amazon-web-services, intellij-idea, aws-sam

I just started building serverless application with aws toolkit in intellij, and I got stuck in this error after executing the template.

```
Build Failed
Error: JavaMavenWorkflow:Resolver - No Maven executable found!
```

I tried a lot of solution in the aws documentation bad none of them works

Comment: Have you installed Maven on your workstation?

Comment: If you mean the mvn install command I executed it

Comment: I suspect there is something wrong with the plugin. I have the MAVEN_HOME environment variable set (using Ubuntu) and the mvn command is available in the terminal tab in IntelliJ. If I copy the failing sam-command from the build tab and try to execute it in the terminal tab, it works.

Answer (score 7):

Click modify run configuration and then select the "Build function inside a container" checkbox on the SAM CLI tab.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error not from IntelliJ but from CLI and eventually, I solved this by:-

**Solution** - Add MAVEN_HOME/path to maven bin to system environment variables so that Mvn command is accessible from anywhere this should solve the problem

Comment: Simply making sure MAVEN_HOME/bin was in the system path seemed to be enough to get this to work for me.  Of course, I did need to download Maven and put it in a subdirectory of Program Files first...

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your maven version is appropriate configured into system variables with comand

```
mvn -v
```

If not then please refer to this answer - [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19090928/mvn-command-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

and configure your MAVEN_HOME.

This should fix the problem.