# 'mvn' command is not recognized as an internal or external command, was working

Tags: maven

Yesterday, I went through a tutorial that had me set up maven, and I got the project working, and shutdown the windows pc.

Now today, the mvn command isn't working.

```
C:\>mvn -version
'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

My system variable:
`MAVEN_HOME=C:\opt\apache-maven-3.6.3`

My path variable includes this at the end:
`;%MAVEN_HOME%\bin`

It looks like my system variable is set up correctly:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that when you're seetting up your *M2_HOME* that it's pointing to you Maven basedir, **NOT** the bin dir.
2. Afterwards, make sure to set the path and **PATH** something like so: (`PATH=%M2_HOME%\bin;%PATH`%).
3. Then restart your machine and run this command.

   ```
   dir %M2_HOME%\bin\mvn*
   ```

---

If there is a `.bat` file, it should work since you seem to run Windows. If there isn't one, then your paths are not right and you need to make sure your `%PATH%` variable points to the correct path to Maven.

Comment: This answer is a copy from a similar question, and doesn't help me, I don't have an M2_HOME value.

Comment: I've updated my initial question with more details.

Comment: what do you mean copy? And you create the M2_HOME value manually if not automatically created after installation.

Comment: The answer you posted can be seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19090928/mvn-command-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Comment: I used MAVEN_HOME instead of M2_HOME, but same steps were followed

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but its working as it should today, no changes were made other than a restart of the windows PC.  Will continue to monitor, but I can't replicate the problem to investigate it anymore.