# AWS SAM Template Errors

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, aws-lambda, aws-sam

I am using VS Code to create and deploy my SAM template and I'm getting the current error:

```
Build Failed
Error: JavaMavenWorkflow:Resolver - No Maven executable found!
```

Does anyone know how to fix this/has anyone dealt with this before?

For a little more information, this is a spring boot application.

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux?

Comment: windows @AllanChua

Answer (score 0):

This error could be thrown by VS Code because `Maven` the build tool used for Java is either not installed, not in the system environment variables resulting to `mvn` command being unavailable/unfindable.

```
mvn -v
```

To solve the problem, please refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19090928/mvn-command-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command#:%7E:text=Right%20click%20on%20My%20Computer%20%3E%3E%20Properties%20%3E%3E%20Advanced%20system%20settings%20%3E%3E%20System%20Properties%20window%20will%20get%20displayed%20Under%20Advanced%20%3E%3E%20Environment%20Variables:%7E:text=Right%20click%20on%20My%20Computer%20%3E%3E%20Properties%20%3E%3E%20Advanced%20system%20settings%20%3E%3E%20System%20Properties%20window%20will%20get%20displayed%20Under%20Advanced%20%3E%3E%20Environment%20Variables) on how to configure your environment variables and make maven accessible in your system.

Another option is to configure your SAM CLI to use containers:

```bash
sam build  --use-container -t template.yml
```

This allows you and your colleagues to have a reproduceable build environments in your own machines.